# Access DOM elements inside iframe from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to acces DOM elements inside an iframe without getting a cross-origin error ?
Basically I want to be able to click a button located inside an iframe to launch a video, from my extension.

I really don't know how to proceed, I have tried `iframe.contentDocument` but I get the cross-origin error.

*background.js:*

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    "file": "script.js",
    "allFrames" : true
});
```

*script.js*:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeId");
var button = iframe.contentDocument.getElementsById("buttonId");
```

The error I get :
 `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://website.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen What do you want me to add to my question ? What is not clear ?

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: @Makyen I added a bit of code but I don't think that's really useful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Brute force: inject a script in the iframe

If you are having trouble accessing the contents of an iframe, the brute force method to do so is to inject a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) directly into the iframe and access the iframe from that content script.

**Inject into a single frame:**
You can explicitly specify the frame into which your script is injected by providing the frame ID in your call to [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). This could be something like:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabOfInterestId,{
    frameId: frameIdToInject,
    file: scriptFileWhichDoesWhatIWantInTheIframe.js
},function(results){
    //Handle any results
});
```

If you don't know the frame ID for the frame into which you desire to inject, you can obtain it from [`chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#method-getAllFrames) like:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames({tabId:tabOfInterestId},function(frames){
    //Do what you want with the array of frame descriptor Objects
});
```

**Injecting into all frames:**
If you want to inject into all frames in a tab, you can do what you show in the Question that you are already doing:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    "file": "script.js",
    "allFrames" : true
});
```

This will inject the *script.js* file into all frames within the active tab of the current window *which exist at the time the `tabs.executeScript()` call is executed*. A different copy of *script.js* will be injected in each frame within the tab, including the base frame. This will not inject *script.js* in any iframes which are added to the tab after this call to `tabs.executeScript()` is made. For iframes, the context in which the injected script exists will be valid (i.e. the script will exist) until the URL for the iframe changes (e.g. the `src` attribute changes), or a parent frame (e.g. the base frame of the tab) changes URL (i.e. a new page is loaded in a parent frame).

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed

Comment: I just have one last question.. Is it possible to fire a DOM event in an inactive tab ? For example firing the `click()` event of a button that is in a different tab than the active one.

Comment: @DavidSeroussi, Yes, you can do so from a content script that is already in that page, or a content script which you inject in that page for the purpose of doing so, even though the tab is not the active tab at the time. Injecting into a tab which is not the active tab at the time the user clicks your browser UI button requires that you have declared permissions for a matching URL.

Comment: Ok, but do you have any idea why a youtube video would launch only when the tab it's contained in is selected ? Because I my script clicks the play button of a media player and it works well when the tab is active, but when the tab is inactive the video won't launch until the tab is focus once. Thank you for your help

Comment: So after some research I found that chrome pauses any media before the tab is focused.. I confirmed this behavior by trying my extension on chromium 45 and everything works well. Do you know how I can disable this 'media pause' ? Or should I ask a new question ?

Comment: @DavidSeroussi, I would have to research it. It is definitely something for which you should ask another question. It sounds like something that would be of general interest, and should not be just in comments.

Comment: @Makyen thanks for the answer. But, what if the frame doesn't have an ID, and it has a name? how can I give a selector here?

Comment: @PrakashPalnati Every frame has a [`frameId`](//developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-detailsType-frameId). It's assigned by Chrome when the frame is created. It's not related to the HTML `id` attribute. If you're asking how to find a specific `<iframe>` from among multiple iframe's on a page (potentially based on an HTML `name` attribute, or other DOM selector), that's a significantly more complex question, which deserves a separate Stack Overflow Question and Answer. How to do it will depend on what other information you have, but usually will be based on the frame's URL.